# Does Visual Studio have a namespace-sensitive macro-substitution option?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

What I'm talking about is to find a way to avoid the macros in `<windows.h>` from polluting whatever project I'm writing.

Excerpts from `windows.h`:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define LoadImage  LoadImageW
#else
#define LoadImage  LoadImageA
#endif // !UNICODE

#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetMessage  GetMessageW
#else
#define GetMessage  GetMessageA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

The majority of macros (over 99%) I'm okay with, but some of them I just couldn't find a way to avoid.

My idea is that since I always qualify the functions calls in my particular framework, e.g. `ImageTool::LoadImage`, Visual Studio should have enough clue that I'm not referencing the Windows API, which are all in the root namespace, i.e. `::LoadImage`. But the MACRO system does not seem to be that smart.

Is there a compiler or preprocessor option that will just enable that?

Comment: Try defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before you include `<windows.h>`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: thanks, that's what I tried. Doesn't help.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is here. You shouldn't be using macros with the same name in your own code. And you should place all of your own code in its own namespace to ensure there are no conflicts with the functions defined by the Windows headers in (unfortunately) the global namespace.

Comment: there are reasons we prefer full-qualified names and dislike using namespace xxx...

Comment: @Cody: `<windows.h>` is a Microsoft include file. Worse, I just found out it's included by the framework header - I might as well modify the framework header (or `<windows.h>`) to suit my needs.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware what `windows.h` is; I spend 99% of my time writing Windows applications. Re-read my comment again. I *still* don't understand what the problem is. Just don't write macros with the same name as those defined in `windows.h`, and you won't have a problem. As well, you should always wrap your *own* functions in your *own* namespace. Yes, it's unfortunate that MS didn't place the Windows functions in a `Windows` namespace, but we can't change that now. And *no*, editing `windows.h` is **not** an option. Don't try doing that.

Comment: @Cody: sorry I may have misunderstood. Inside the framework there are some C++ class methods that are just named `LoadImage` and alike. For native C++ project this is okay because they will just be "quietly batch-renamed" to `LoadImageW` and the project will still compile okay. The problem is that when I need to export the DLL or to another C++/CLI project, those "macro effects" will become visible, and because .Net doesn't have the same macro effects, people will wonder why the documentation says `LoadImage` but they have to call it with `LoadImageW` whenever in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macro substitution are basically simple textual replacements, done before the proper compiler even starts to parse the code. Therefore they are not aware of namespaces or any other parts of the C++ syntax above the pure lexical level.

The straight forward way to avoid replacement of your identifiers is to remove the macros:

```
#ifdef LoadImage
#undef LoadImage
#endif
```

This of course will also stop following code from accessing the Windows API with the name `LoadImage`.

Comment: Thanks. If I ever need to access the Windows API, I can use their "true name", e.g. `::LoadImageW` including the proper suffix. I'm just wondering if the VC++ preprocessor has an option to at least lex the scope resolution operator.

Comment: It's called *pre*-processor for a reason. ;)

Comment: Preprocessor has to parse at the "tokens" level. Otherwise, it couldn't do a proper job of substituting strings that might be part of a string literal. Thus, preprocessor has proper knowledge that something is preceded by the scope resolution operator `"::"`. This token is easy to parse - two otherwise consecutive colons (or whitespace-separated colons) has no meaning.

Comment: @rwong: that would violate the standards, both C and C++ (<windows.h> works for both).

Answer (score 1):

You will to live with it - you cannot avoid these macros on Windows platform. There is no macro-name-spacing in C/C++ pre-processor world. You may however, have all of your code defined and implemented before including any windows header - but that's wouldn't be possible, I believe.

Comment: I decide to make a local copy of `<windows.h>`, edit it to my pleasure, and call it `my_windows_is_leaner_and_meaner_than_yours.h`, and store it as one of my project header files. I know I can't redistribute that file; my situation is okay with that.

Comment: Not worth the pain! You need to maintain the header very much regularly, other headers/libraries will not work as expected! Warned you! :)

Comment: The `windows.h` is only updated for every release of [Windows Platform SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924) - given the lengths of their past release cycles, I'm okay with this hassle.